# What's the correct way to fill a DropDownList using LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I know this question might be duplicate but I have a look at tons of examples but none of them suit my situation.

I have a DropDownList inside a DataList, I need to populate DropDownList with data from the DB. I know how to find the the dropdown control in the DataList and I know how to populate the dropdown using SqlCommand. Now I'm trying to learn LINQ but I'm unable to fill the dropdown. Please see my scenarios below:

```
        //Scenario 1
        var ddquery = from dd in db.PRODUCTs select dd.pr_product.Distinct();

        product.DataSource = ddquery;                
        product.DataTextField = "pr_product";
        product.DataValueField = "pr_product";
        product.DataBind();
```

In Scenario 1 I get error:  "Sequence operators not supported for type 'System.String'."

```
        //Scenario 2
        var ddproc = from dd in db.isp_GETDDL("PRODUCTS", "", "") select dd;

        product.DataSource = ddproc;
        product.DataTextField = "pr_product";
        product.DataValueField = "pr_product";
        product.DataBind();
```

In Scenario 2 the I get error: "DataBinding: 'isp_GETDDLResult' does not contain a property with the name 'pr_product'." In this scenario I'm not really if I'm doing it right since the PROC returns a set of data but I'm not sure if I'm handling correctly.

```
        //Scenario 3
        var ddq = from dd in db.PRODUCTs select dd;

        product.DataSource = ddq;
        product.DataTextField = "pr_product";
        product.DataValueField = "pr_product";
        product.DataBind();
```

In Scenario 3, I get the same error as in 2 but on this one I'm not using a PROC to get the data.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, all three answers I get no error but the DropDownList is NOT being fill. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I figure it out. One of the conditions in my code was not being met. All three answer are valid but can only mark one as the answer sorry :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like your `Distinct` call should be on query itself, not on one value within results:

```
var ddquery = (from dd in db.PRODUCTs select dd.pr_product).Distinct().ToList();
```

And what more important, you don't have to specify `DataTextField` and `DataValueField`, because your `DataSource` is `List<string>`:

```
product.DataSource = ddquery;                
product.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `pr_product` is type `string` this should work

```
    //Scenario 1
    var ddquery = from dd in db.PRODUCTs select dd.pr_product.Distinct();

    product.DataSource = ddquery;                
    product.DataBind();
```

Following my assumption, `ddquery` will be `IEnumerable<string>` so you don't have to specify the field name on databind, and it's actually wrong for this case.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "is type string"?

Answer (score 0):

(Alternative, using anonymous types)

```
product.Datasource = ddquery.Select(d => new 
{
pr_product = d.something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

other way..

```
1.var query=(from p in ContexName.TableName
2.          select new{
3.                 p.fieldName

4.          }).toArray();
5.for(int i=0;i<query.count();i++)
6.        dropdownlist.items.add(query[i].FieldName.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategorie" runat="server">                         
</asp:DropDownList>
```

In the code behind file:

```
ddlCategorie.DataSource = context.Categories.ToList();
ddlCategorie.DataTextField = "Nom";
ddlCategorie.DataValueField = "CategorieId";
ddlCategorie.DataBind();
ddlCategorie.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-Séléctionner une catégorie-"));
```